# InvalidCastException in MySqlConnector while Math.Round inside LINQ-to-Entities

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, mysql-connector

I have a question that I can not answer myself for now. The problem arose in the real scenario, but I simplified it for the question. I just wanted to make the rounding inside Select in LINQ. Perhaps it should be done in another way?

The following code works as expected:

```
var test = Math.Round(99.00000000000000000000000000m, 3); // 99.000m
var testLinq1 = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>() { "dummy" }
    .Select(r => new
    {
        value = Math.Round(99.00000000000000000000000000m, 3) // 99.000m
    })
    .ToList();
```

But both of these lines throw an exception:

```
var testLinq2 = _dbContext.SomeEntity
    .Select(r => new
    {
        value = Math.Round(99.00000000000000000000000000m) // Throws an exception.
    })
    .ToList();

var testLinq3 = _dbContext.SomeEntity
    .Select(r => new
    {
        value = Math.Round(99.00000000000000000000000000m, 3) // Throws an exception.
    })
    .ToList();
```

The exception is:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Decimal'.
>
> InnerException: null
>
> Source: MySqlConnector

StackTrace is:

```
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32 ordinal)
at lambda_method(Closure , DbDataReader )
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactory.Create(DbDataReader dataReader)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.MySqlQueryingEnumerable`1.MySqlEnumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at ProjectName.Controllers.SomeController.SomeAction(Int32 propertyId) in D:\Work\Project\ProjectName\Controllers\SomeController.cs:line 419
at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionFilterAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
```

It's

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "type": "platform"
}
```

And I'm using

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.1",
"Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql": "1.1.1"
```

### Update

Thanks to Tim Schmelter it's obvious now that in the first case it's Linq-to-Objects, and in the second case it's Linq-to-Entities and Math.Round is translated to SQL. Given the formulation of the question, this could even be considered an answer. But I'm curious, purely hypothetically, what if I want to use the MySQL server rounding function? Why this code works fine with SQL Server Compact DB, as James Curran said, but it's not working with MySQL? It's looked like a bug of the connector.

Comment: In the first version you are using `Linq-To-Objects` in the second you are using `Linq-To-Entities`, the `Math.Round` is translated to sql. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Using Linq2SQL and a SQL SErver Compact DB, those line work.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick comments. So the problem is caused by the incorrect conversion into SQL with aforementioned connector or it should be done in another way to make round operations by MySQL server in this case?

Comment: @TimSchmelter In EF Core though one never knows what is translated to SQL and what is evaluated in memory :)

Comment: If moving the "ToList" prior to the select, the transformation will be done in L2O.

Comment: Yes, it's obvious now that in the first case it's Linq-to-Objects, and in the second case it's Linq-to-Entities and Math.Round is translated to SQL, as Tim Schmelter said. Given the formulation of the question, this could even be considered an answer. But I'm curious, purely hypothetically, what if I want to use the MySQL server rounding function? Why this code works fine with SQL Server Compact DB, as James Curran said, but it's not working with MySQL? It's looked like a bug of the connector.